# Is there a way to take the output of a (HH24:MI:SS - HH24:MI:SS) and convert it to only minutes in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle-sqldeveloper

So i am putting the sql code in that i have shown below and my output that i get from the ProcessEnd minus ProcessStart is the duration time which comes out as "0 0:0:8.135". However, i need it to only show in terms of minutes, i don't want the hours or seconds, just the minutes the process runs.

```
TO_CHAR(rh.PROCESSSTART,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "PROCESSSTART",
TO_CHAR(rh.PROCESSEND,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "PROCESSEND",
(rh.PROCESSEND - rh.PROCESSSTART) AS "DURATION",
```

"0 0:0:8.135"

Answer (score 0):

It looks that `PROCESSEND` and `PROCESSSTART` are `DATE`s.

If so, subtracting them results in number of days.

In order to get number of minutes, you'll have to multiply number of days by

- 24, as there are 24 hours in a day
- 60, as there are 60 minutes in an hour

so the final result would be

```
(rh.processend - rh.processstart) * 24 * 60 as number_of_minutes
```